# How do we read GIT commit message inside an Azure DevOps build pipeline?

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to read the actual GIT commit message inside an Azure build pipeline?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You have a [pre-defined variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables) with the commit message:

```
Build.SourceVersionMessage
```

> The comment of the commit or changeset for the triggering repo. This
>   variable is agent-scoped, and can be used as an environment variable
>   in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as part of the
>   build number or as a version control tag. Also, this variable is only
>   available on the step level and is neither available in the job nor
>   stage levels (i.e. the message is not extracted until the job had
>   started and checked out the code).

Comment: These many days I was writing a script to fetch the last commit message. This is simple and clean. Thank you.

Comment: FYI it doesn't look like this is available on the Release pipelines for deployment scripts  Script it is!