# Get list of commits messages since previous build in an Azure Devops Pipeline custom extension task

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

I'm implementing a custom extension in which I need to get the list of commit messages since the previous build in an Azure Devops Pipeline.

```
Build n (commit n, commit n-1)
Build n-1 (commit n-2, commit n-3)
```

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62268742/how-do-we-read-git-commit-message-inside-an-azure-devops-build-pipeline) points at the `Build.SourceVersionMessage` as a way to get the commit message. I tried it but **it only references the last commit** `commit n`, instead of `commit n, commit n-1`:

```
          - task: MyTask@0
            inputs:
              commitMessage: '$(Build.SourceVersionMessage)'
```

```
import tl = require('azure-pipelines-task-lib/task');

async function run() {
    try {
        const commitMessage = tl.getInput("commitMessage", true) as string
        console.log('commitMessage', commitMessage);
    } catch (err) {
        tl.setResult(tl.TaskResult.Failed, err.message);
    }
}

run();
```

How can I get all the messages since the previous build?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no feature that can meet your requirements now.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I opened a feature request to ask for this improvement: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=21&q=get+list+commit+messages